# WSO2 Governance Registry Error

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I am working on the integration of the `EI 6.1.1` with the  registry 5.4.0..
I have placed the car files in the `Greg server` and referred the `Governance Registry` from the `EI6.1.1` as below

In registry.xml,provided the Greg url with user and passwd
as `https: localhost:9445/registry`

When I start the `EI` ,I am receiving errors like

> ERROR org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.AuthorisationUtils Could not
>   set authorisations for the root

But I am able to login to the `GREG` console
Will this error have any impact on the `Greg` process

Please help me in resolving the error..

Comment: There should be additional logs with this error. Could you please update the question with the full stack trace?

Comment: I receive the following before the error mentioned above..(org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authentication.JDBC )Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manger privilege block.;; could not set authorization for the root;;java.lang.Nullpointerexception--Tenant domain has not been set in Carbontext;;org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry---Failed to add the root collection to the coreRegistry